# Updating Datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to figure out how to update a selected row in my DataGridView. I would like my system to recognize an existing row of information I've selected from my datagridview (I've set it to full row select btw) and update/edit the information by changing them with the textboxes and comboboxes I used to add them. Everything in my table is set as Text datatype, besides ID which is auto number. However, I get an error with the code I used below. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you :) (I'm gonna provide a link to the screenshot of the error since I don't have enough reputation.) 
*** New error when I enclose Section with brackets**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXqPi.png

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class AdmMain

Dim con As New OleDbConnection

Sub fillcombo()
    strsql = " select yrgr from yearandgrade"
    Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    acscmd.CommandText = strsql
    acscmd.Connection = acsconn
    acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

    While (acsdr.Read())
        cboyr.Items.Add(acsdr("yrgr"))
    End While
    acscmd.Dispose()
    acsdr.Close()
End Sub

Sub comb2()
    strsql = " select sections from sectio"
    Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    acscmd.CommandText = strsql
    acscmd.Connection = acsconn
    acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

    While (acsdr.Read())
        cbosec.Items.Add(acsdr("sections"))
    End While
    acscmd.Dispose()
    acsdr.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to logout?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged out of VCM's Library Information System!", "Logout Confirmed")
        Me.Close()
        LoginUser.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.TxtID.Text = ""
    Me.txtFName.Text = ""
    Me.txtMName.Text = ""
    Me.txtLName.Text = ""
    Me.cboyr.Text = ""
    Me.cbosec.Text = ""
    Me.TxtID.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub AdmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Module1.connect()
    Me.fillcombo()
    Me.comb2()


    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"

    con.Open()

    datagridshow()
End Sub

Private Sub datagridshow()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from students ", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim rbdtext As String = cboyr.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim uno As String = cbosec.SelectedItem.ToString

    Try
        Dim cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                     "Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"
        Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO students " & _
            "(StudentID, FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Yr, [Section]) " & _
            "VALUES (@studid, @fname,@mname,@lname,@yr, @sec)"

        ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
        ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

        Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
            Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, conn)

                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studid", TxtID.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtMName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", rbdtext)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", uno)

                If TxtID.Text = "" Or txtFName.Text = "" Or txtMName.Text = "" Or txtLName.Text = "" Or cboyr.SelectedIndex = -1 Or cbosec.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                    Return
                Else
                    Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If rowsInserted > 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("One record successfully added!", "Added!")
                        datagridshow()
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Failure to add new record!", "Failure!")
                    End If
                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TxtID_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtID.KeyPress

    '97 - 122 = Ascii codes for simple letters
    '65 - 90  = Ascii codes for capital letters
    '48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    Dim rbdtext As String = cboyr.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim uno As String = cbosec.SelectedItem.ToString

    Try
        Dim cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                     "Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"
        Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE Students SET StudentID = @STUDID, FirstName = @FNAME, MiddleName = @MNAME, LastName= @LNAME, Yr = @YRR, [Section] = @SEC WHERE StudentID = @STUDID, FirstName =@FNAME, MiddleName = @MNAME, LastName= @LNAME, Yr = @YRR, [Section] = @SEC"



        ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
        ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

        Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
            Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, conn)

                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDID", TxtID.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", txtFName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNAME", txtMName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", txtLName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YRR", rbdtext)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC", uno)

                If TxtID.Text = "" Or txtFName.Text = "" Or txtMName.Text = "" Or txtLName.Text = "" Or cboyr.SelectedIndex = -1 Or cbosec.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                    Return
                Else
                    Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If rowsInserted > 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("One record successfully updated!", "Updated!")
                        datagridshow()
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Failure to update new record!", "Failure!")
                    End If
                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have I already told you that SECTION is a reserved keyword?

Comment: I forgot sorry. I still get an error even with the Section enclosed with brackets http://i.imgur.com/gs8rVhB.png @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of a UPDATE...WHERE expression requires a condition that uniquely identifies the record to UPDATE. If the condition is an expression composed of more than one field/value then these conditions should be combined using AND or OR operators not using commas.

Usually the condition in the WHERE clause identifies the record to be updated using the PRIMARY KEY of the table (in your case this seems to be the StudentID field) so you just need to write

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE Students SET FirstName = @FNAME, " &_ 
                         "MiddleName = @MNAME, LastName= @LNAME, Yr = @YRR, " & _ 
                         "[Section] = @SEC " & _ 
                         "WHERE StudentID = @STUDID"
```

Note that if StudentID is the PRIMARYKEY you don't try to change/update it bacause this could cause inconsistencies in your other database tables that refer (have a relationship) with the Students table

Finally, the OleDb provider don't recognize the parameter by their name, the provider expects that each parameter passed is in the same order in which the parameter placeholders appears in the command text (It use the position of the parameter to pass the value to the database engine), so you need to change also the order in which you set up the parameter collection for the UPDATE

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", txtFName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNAME", txtMName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", txtLName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YRR", rbdtext)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEC", uno)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDID", TxtID.Text)
```

Comment: It did remove the long list of errors. But it showed failure to update record (which is also in the code) I don't know what's causing it to fail? Is it because of the datagrid?

Comment: Did you get an error message through the exception or it is just "Failure to update new record"?

Comment: Then there is no record corresponding to the value used for StudentID